# 1 Push Notification SSL Certificate for multiple apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there anyone out there who knows if it's possible to use 1 production SSL push notification certificate for multiple apps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you need one per app-id.

Comment: Yes, this is an intentional limitation.

Comment: That's why you can't use a wildcard app id.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Each App ID is required to have its own client SSL certificate.
For more information [Check Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW11)

> The client SSL certificate that is generated is a universal
>   certificate that allows your app to connect to both the **development**
>   and **production** environments.
>
> **Not use as a wildcard AppId because...**
>    You can create only one
>   explicit App ID that matches your bundle ID. Therefore, if Xcode
>   created an explicit App ID for you—for example, when you added another
>   capability that requires an explicit App ID—you should use it;
>   otherwise, you create an explicit App ID that matches your bundle ID.
>   You then generate and download a corresponding client SSL
>   certificate—this step fully enables push notifications—and refresh
>   provisioning profiles in Xcode. Later, you install the client SSL
>   certificate and key on your server.